# Check Bluetooth off without Systemhint

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an app that connects to a peripheral by BLE.
How do I check bluetooth is off without an iOS system dialog?

Currently I listen to didUpdateState in the CBCentralManagerDelegate. But if bluetooth is powered off I get the event AND a system ui dialog telling me to activate bluetooth in settings.

[image]

Is there another way to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are specifying `false` for the [`CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanageroptionshowpoweralertkey) when you instantiate your `CBCentralManager` object